# Hashicorp Vagrant - How to authenticate against SMB if I have Microsoft Account on my windows host

Tags: vagrant, smb, vagrant-windows, hashicorp, microsoft-account

I have a windows 10 host and I would like to set up Synced Folders for my vagrant box. In my Vagrantfile I have:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/vagrant_data"
end
```

When I start up (or reload) my box, I get prompted for credentials:

```
PS D:\Vagrants\first> vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default: Configuring the VM...
    default: Setting VM Enhanced session transport type to disabled/default (VMBus)
==> default: Starting the machine...
==> default: Waiting for the machine to report its IP address...
    default: Timeout: 120 seconds
    default: IP: 172.27.23.149
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 172.27.23.149:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Preparing SMB shared folders...
    default: You will be asked for the username and password to use for the SMB
    default: folders shortly. Please use the proper username/password of your
    default: account.
    default:
    default: Username (user[@domain]):
```

Either format I try to specify my microsoft credentials, it gets rejected. I tried both with and without windows PIN. Suppose my Microsoft account is `username@outlook.com` and password is `mypass`. Workgroup name on my windows machine is `WORKGROUP`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the vagrant tag: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by:

- disabling the Windows PIN and
- as username using my "local" windows username (determined by windows environment variable `%username%` which also seems to equal to the folder named under `C:\Users\USERNAME`. Note that this is **not** the same as my Microsoft Account username) and
- as password using my Microsoft Account password